# Turn series to columns in Kusto/Azure Data Explorer

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I am trying to turn a Windows event log xml event data in Azure Logs (kusto) into columns, so given the EventData array in the xml as returned by parse_xml(),how do I turn it into columns?

I tried mvexplode which gave me rows (series), but then I would like to turn those into columns where col name is the attribute "Name" in the  tag and value is the text property.

Windows event log xml below for reference

`<EventData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <Data Name="DomainPolicyChanged">Password Policy</Data>
  <Data Name="DomainName">XXX</Data>
  <Data Name="DomainSid">S-1-5-21-....</Data>
  <Data Name="SubjectUserSid">S-1-5-18</Data>
  <Data Name="SubjectUserName">SRV-XX-001$</Data>
  <Data Name="SubjectDomainName">DOMAIN</Data>
  <Data Name="SubjectLogonId">0x3e7</Data>
  <Data Name="PrivilegeList">-</Data>
  <Data Name="MinPasswordAge"></Data>
  <Data Name="MaxPasswordAge"></Data>
  <Data Name="ForceLogoff"></Data>
  <Data Name="LockoutThreshold">耠</Data>
  <Data Name="LockoutObservationWindow"></Data>
  <Data Name="LockoutDuration"></Data>
  <Data Name="PasswordProperties">耠-</Data>
  <Data Name="MinPasswordLength">-</Data>
  <Data Name="PasswordHistoryLength">-</Data>
  <Data Name="MachineAccountQuota">-</Data>
  <Data Name="MixedDomainMode">1</Data>
  <Data Name="DomainBehaviorVersion">8</Data>
  <Data Name="OemInformation">12</Data>
</EventData>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach could work
(depending on how you actually plan to query the data, there could be a more efficient way - so if you could share a sample query, it could be helpful)

```
datatable(someColumn:string, xmlValue:string)
["hello", '<EventData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">\r\n'
  '<Data Name="DomainBehaviorVersion">8</Data>\r\n'
  '<Data Name="OemInformation">12</Data>\r\n'
  '<Data Name="DomainPolicyChanged">Password Policy</Data>\r\n'
  '<Data Name="DomainName">XXX</Data>\r\n'
  '<Data Name="DomainSid">S-1-5-21-....</Data>\r\n'
  '<Data Name="SubjectUserSid">S-1-5-18</Data>\r\n'
  '<Data Name="SubjectUserName">SRV-XX-001$</Data>\r\n'
  '<Data Name="SubjectDomainName">DOMAIN</Data>\r\n'
  '<Data Name="SubjectLogonId">0x3e7</Data>\r\n'
  '<Data Name="PrivilegeList">-</Data>\r\n'
  '<Data Name="MinPasswordAge"></Data>\r\n'
  '<Data Name="MaxPasswordAge"></Data>\r\n'
  '<Data Name="ForceLogoff"></Data>\r\n'
  '<Data Name="LockoutThreshold">耠</Data>\r\n'
  '<Data Name="LockoutObservationWindow"></Data>\r\n'
  '<Data Name="LockoutDuration"></Data>\r\n'
  '<Data Name="PasswordProperties">耠-</Data>\r\n'
  '<Data Name="MinPasswordLength">-</Data>\r\n'
  '<Data Name="PasswordHistoryLength">-</Data>\r\n'
  '<Data Name="MachineAccountQuota">-</Data>\r\n'
  '<Data Name="MixedDomainMode">1</Data>\r\n'
'</EventData>',
"world", '<EventData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">\r\n'
  '<Data Name="DomainBehaviorVersion">876543</Data>\r\n'
  '<Data Name="OemInformation">12345</Data>\r\n'
'</EventData>'
]
| extend parsed = parse_xml(xmlValue).EventData.Data
| mvexpand parsed
| summarize d = make_bag(pack(tostring(parsed['@Name']), parsed['#text'])) by someColumn
| evaluate bag_unpack(d)
```

Docs for operators/functions used in this example:

- datatable operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/datatableoperator
- parse_xml function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/parse-xmlfunction
- mvexpand operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/mvexpandoperator
- make_bag aggregation function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/make-bag-aggfunction
- pack function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/packfunction
- bag_unpack plugin: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/bag-unpackplugin

Comment: Yoni epic hackery!

Comment: hey, it seems that make_dictionary has disappared?

Comment: try `make_bag()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/make-bag-aggfunction